# Product show up in search, but not in category

Tags: magento-1.9, product

Product show up as  search result , but not in category in the specific category.

Please help

Comment: Please specify Magento version.

Comment: Yes please specify it. But have you checked if your products `visibility` is set to `search only` or those are not even assigned to any `category`.

Comment: Hello , thanks for the quick response.  Version is 1.9.0.1. Product_Visibility: catalog and search.   I have 10 results in search for an specific category  item but the categery value is (1). Even those (1) did't appear

Comment: if i click in front end the specific categry i got following msg There are no products matching the selection

Comment: You want to: Product show in search result  and category page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reidnex or cache flush.

From commandline run and **from your Magento installation root path**:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindexall
rm -rf var/cache/*
```

If you are using an external cache engine (e.g.: redis) you will need to flush cache from backend.

I am pretty sure it will fix your problem.

Comment: For info, you can also reindex and flush the cache from the admin interface

Comment: Yep correct. I suggested him to do from CLI to avoid timeouts in reindexing since I believe his problem is there, but your comment is correct.